# Managing string resources in Qt

Tags: qt

I have a string that I need at various points in my program. I know that Qt can manage image resources, but I need similar functionality for a couple of strings. Currently I'm using a string resource class, which is a [sloppy solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_%28computer_programming%29).

```
class StringRes {
public:
    static const QString& appName() { return _appName; }
    static const QString& appVersion() { return _appVersion; }
private:
    static const QString _appName;
    static const QString _appVersion;
};
```

Besides, this solution causes a segfault at a certain point in my code.

```
_fileStream << QString("This is ")
               + StringRes::appName()
               + " "
               + StringRes::appVersion()
               + " reporting for duty.\n";
```

How do Qt programmers (or C++ programmers in general) manage their string resources?

Comment: For application's name and version and organization's name and website you can use [QCoreApplication](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QCoreApplication.html) properties. They are exactly static member variables of QCoreApplication class, so your solution isn't that bad.

Comment: @Claudio +1 Agreed, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Claudio: Cool, I didn't know that existed. If you post it as an answer I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing just application's name and version and organization's name and domain you can use [QCoreApplications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QCoreApplication.html)'s properties applicationName, applicationVersion, organizationDomain and organizationName.

I usually set them in `main()` function:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // These functions are member of QCoreApplication, QApplication's
    // parent class:
    app.setApplicationName("My Application");
    app.setApplicationVersion("3.5.2");
    app.setOrganizationName("My Company, or just My Name");
    app.setOrganizationDomain("http://example.com/");

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

And I can use them to show a nice about message:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QCoreApplication>

...

// Slot called when ? -> About menu is clicked.
void MainWindow::on_aboutAction_triggered()
{
    QString message = tr("<strong>%1</strong> %2<br />"
                         "Developed by %3")
            .arg(QCoreApplication::applicationName())
            .arg(QCoreApplication::applicationVersion())
            .arg(QString("<a href=\"%1\">%2</a>")
                .arg(QCoreApplication::organizationDomain())
                .arg(QCoreApplication::organizationName()))
            ;

    QMessageBox::about(this, tr("About"), message);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, Claudio!